# Send a long click (or any touch event) to a View in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing

When doing unit testing in Android activities  using  [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase.html) you could  use [TouchUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) to "send" a long click to a view in the activity with `longClickView (ActivityInstrumentationTestCase test, View v)`

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase` was deprecated in favour of [`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html).
So the `longClickView` is no longer available; it is deprecated and recommends using  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 "which provides more options for configuring the Activity under test"

I cannot find how to do this operation (sending a touch event to a view) in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`.
Can anyone show me an example of how to do this now?

**EDIT**

Further addition to the question. Is there anyway I can get the test to wait on a textview being updated. I have a button which fetches something from the network and displays it in a TextView. I'd like to test pressing that button and then examining the resulting text.

**EDIT 2**

I'm sorry for continuing to add to this question but they are related. So...when I press that button I expect the vibrator to vibrate. Is there an accepted was to confirm that this has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596397/testing-with-ui-elements-in-android-view) in SO.

Is this the recommended way to go? To call the `performLongClick()` and `performClick()` methods on the buttons directly?

Comment: I'm searching for the same information, but this appears to be correct. If you've found something different, please post! :)

Comment: TouchUtils.longClickView(test, view)