# How do I interact with UI Components from within ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, junit, instrumentation

I'm trying to learn how to write instrumentation tests for Android. I have a class which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in order to test my Activity. In one of my tests I try to do the following:

```
Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.performClick() // this method throws CalledFromWrongThreadException
```

From reading around it sounds like I can't interact with UI components in this way - I have to either create a new runnable and run it on the UI thread ([Testing with UI elements in Android view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596397/testing-with-ui-elements-in-android-view)) or run the whole test on the UI thread using @UiThreadTest ([Android: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views - UnitTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754500/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)). However, the former solution is very cumbersome and the latter simply didn't work for me (the same exception gets thrown).

What I would like is to be able to interact directly with the button as the [testing fundamentals documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) seems to suggest is possible (at least for a Spinner). Is this possible or do I have to worry about running on different threads like the first link suggests?

Comment: Have you tired this `TouchUtils.clickView(this, mClickMeButton);`

Comment: Amazing! That worked. Thank you. Can you tell me why that worked but not the way described in the Testing documentation nor using the @UiThreadTest annotation?

Comment: Instrumentation is functional test so to perform touch you need to use `TouchUtils` rather than `onClick()` which will work with `unit test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Muhammed Babar in the comments, I needed to use TouchUtils.clickView()